# what is the correct syntax for new SelectList(_roleManager.Roles.Where(s => s.Name == "User" && s => s.Name == "GroupAdmin")

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to only include these two options in my drop down but I don't know & can't find the proper syntax for my logic. please help if you can.

```
new SelectList(_roleManager.Roles.Where(s => s.Name == "User" && s => s.Name == "GroupAdmin")
```

Comment: Name will be either user or group administrator. Change && to || operator

Comment: also, change that ==  to .Equals (strings are immutable)

Answer (score 0):

You neeed to select Value and Text fields as minimum for select list.

Asumming Role.Id for Value and Role.Name for Text you can use this code

```
var selectList =new SelectList(_roleManager.Roles.Where(s => s.Name == "User" || s.Name == "GroupAdmin")
.ToList(),"Id","Name");
```

Another way

```
var selectList = new SelectList( _roleManager.Roles.Where(s => s.Name == "User" || s.Name == "GroupAdmin")
.Select( r=> new SelectListItem {Value= r.Id.ToString), Text=r.Name}).ToList());
```